Is it possible to translate text in a chrome extension using Chrome's API?
I am developing a chrome extension that requires translating text between different languages. I would prefer to avoid making external API calls to a paid service such as Google Translation API and the free alternatives often depend on Google Translate and hence are blocked and require proxies.
Chrome has a rich API for developers, and I am wondering whether I could leverage it to translate text. ChatGPT has provided me with several answers that all turned out to be wrong, for instance with the chrome.tabs, chrome.scripting, and Chrome i18n APIs.
Basically, I would like a function like this:
function translateText(text, srcLanguage, destLanguage){

} 

Is there any way to implement that with Chrome's API, or there might be in the future?

There's no such API for extensions.
